# Is there a term for cutting, planing and jointing wood?

Tags: woodworking, lumber, table-saw

Say I buy some two-by lumber from a Big Box retailer. But, for my project, the lumber is a little bit too wide and thick. So in addition to cutting it to length, I need to plane it down to the right thickness, and also make some length-wise rip cuts with a table saw. Finally I might need to run it through a jointer to make sure I'm working with 90° edges all over.

Is there a term for all of these cuts/preparations? Is *milling* the correct term, or is it something else? Essentially a term for "*taking rough lumber and caressing it down to the exact right dimensions.*"

(I'm looking for a term to search for so I can ask Google if there's someone near me who does this as a service, because I don't have $2K to spend on all these tools!)

Comment: You'd run it through a jointer first. The jointer renders one side smooth, so you have a baseline to start planing from.  And the table saw is what gives you the 90 degree edges.  You could also buy lumber from better sources.  Your local family-owned lumberyard generally has better wood at a competitive price.

Comment: Custom woodworking be my best guess.  Adding in the custom will point to the places that will do work for a customer off the street, instead of doing their own work/jobs or only from companies.

Comment: Any professional woodworker or cabinet maker (those would be the search terms I would use)  should have those tools and be able to make it the dimensions you specify.

Comment: Hmmm, I might coin a woodworking term then! How about.... "_boardmaking_". As in "_My piece of wood was not the right size, so I brought it to a woodworker who boardmade it to the right size for me..._"

Comment: "small custom cabinet shop"

Comment: For the love of god don't mill 2x construction lumber and use it for projects

Comment: @whatsisname why not? Lots of wood workers have made workbenches out of SPF 2x4, milled to size, and have had them last for many, many years. Others use 2x material for "country classic" type looks and sell it for a _lot_ of money. Selecting _good_ SPF is required, but heck, I do that for my building projects, not just woodworking projects...

Comment: Check out [woodworking.se] for your woodworking type questions, @hotmeatballsoup. _Loads_ of good info there!

Comment: @whatsisname  Depends upon the project.   If you go thru the available lumber and pick it over, you can find some decent stuff. Recently during a remodel my contractor  got 2x4s for a new wall that were darn near CVG, fortunately there are several leftovers I can use later. And if they need to be stained dark, it matters even less.  2x4s for a nice table, NOPE unless you want the "country" look, but for less demanding projects, if  you can find good ones, I see no problem with it.

Comment: @FreeMan: because by the time you dry the material, cut it down to avoid the knots/pith, deal with the sap pockets, etc not only does the waste close the cost differential substantially, but it's also got a huge hassle factor. Additionally, just because someone sells garbage to unwise buyers for a premium, (e.g. pallet furniture) doesn't mean it's a good material in the general sense. I'm not saying don't use 2x4s for any projects, just ones where you need to mill it into S4S boards first.

Comment: Either you're _much_ more picky thank I am, @whatsisname, or your lumber supplier has _much_ worse lumber than mine. Granted, I have to pick through the piles to get good lumber, but I rarely run into _serious_ knots, sap pockets, etc. Let's agree to disagree on this one, as it sounds like we're each coming from personal experiences and that ours are on opposite ends of the spectrum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Who ever you find, the correct term for the woodworking you described as needing is **milling**, so you got that right.

The normal sequence for prepping lumber/boards that aren't quite perfect or the dimensions don't meet your needs is  to flat plane the board first on a jointer, yeah, flat side down to make a perfect surface. Then plane it to the desired thickness.    If you plane a warped board you end up with a planed warped board, which is why best practice is to get one very true surface first.  Once planed  to the desired thickness, using the jointer make an edge pass to true up one side of the board, then using a table saw cut it to the desired width.  I know you may not have all these tools, but hopefully this provides some guidance if you decide to proceed with a mill shop.  They should know all of this, but if they don't, go someplace else.